# Show UserLocation annotation On mapBox ios

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, userlocation

Hi I have issue showing the user location on the MapBox mapView in iOS.
can't show user location for the second time after user denied the permission and authorised from the setting even I'm observing the `authorizationStatus` changes and updating the UI whenever permission is `authorized`.

- `mapView.showsUserLocation = true`
- remove the all annotation from map and add them again

non of those solution worked for me I'm not sure is this problem related for map box only

Comment: Maybe try setting the userLocationTrackingMode.

Comment: Does it work if you close and restart the app?

Comment: @Geru I tried it is not working. I think is bug on the Mapbox I tried the same thing on  MapKit it is working fine.

Comment: @jmkiley yes it it is working when I restart the app that's why we decided to leave it like that because is considered as minor bug.